# ReferenceError: "BarSeriesImpl" is not defined

Tags: birt

My report works fine in BIRT- it shows some Bar chart graphic.
But when I import in some system (IBM maximo) I am getting this error instead of displaying the bar chart:

ReferenceError: "BarSeriesImpl" is not defined. at line 8 of chart script:''

I used this script to show me some values on Bar chart.

```
importPackage( Packages.java.util );
importPackage( Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.type.impl );


function afterDataSetFilled(series, dataSet, icsc)
{

if( series.getClass() == BarSeriesImpl ){

var inv =
parseInt(icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("IN"));
var outv =
parseInt(icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("OUT"));
var canv =
parseInt(icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("CANCELED"));

var narray1 = new ArrayList( );
narray1.add(inv);
narray1.add(outv);
narray1.add(canv);
dataSet.setValues(narray1);
}else{
var catArray = new ArrayList();
catArray.add("IN");
catArray.add("OUT");
catArray.add("CANCELED");
dataSet.setValues(catArray);
}

}
```

How to solve this? Does I have to import somehow this class in my system or ..?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm resurrecting an old question but this just caught my eye because it was similar to [another post](http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/29727-error-message-when-trying-to-use-birt-debugger/) I answered this week.  I think you might be missing org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.type.impl.BarSeriesImp in the systems that you are getting this error message.  I think if you add the BIRT runtime jars to the lib path then it should resolve that error.